# C strcat inserts garbage into string

Tags: c, file, strcat, garbage, getc

My method reads an input text of vectors with the following format:

```
57.0000,-7.4703,-0.3561
81.0000,-4.6478,7.9474
69.0000,-8.3768,0.4391
18.0000,-4.9377,9.9903
62.0000,-5.8751,-6.6054
...
```

My attempt to read each vector and insert it to an array is as follows:

```
FILE *file;
int n = 1, dim, i=0;
char* str;
double ret;
double* X;
int c;
int com=0;
assert(argc==2 && "argc != 2");
file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
assert(file && "file is empty");
for(c = getc(file); c!= EOF; c = getc(file)){
   if(c == '\n'){
        n++;
   }
   else if(c==','){
       com++;
   }
}
dim = com/n +1;
char* str;
double ret;
double* X;
X = (double *)calloc(n*n, sizeof(double));
assert(X); 
str = (char *)calloc(100, sizeof(char));
assert(str); 
for(c = getc(file); c!= EOF; c = getc(file)){
     if(c!=',' && c!= '\n'){
       strcat(str, &c);      
     }
     else{
     ret = strtod(str, NULL);
     X[i] = ret;
     i++;
     memset(str, 0, 100 * sizeof(char)); 
     }
}
```

The problem is that when it gets to the last vector at each line, it reads each char and concatenates it with extra garbage into str. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Show how/where you open the file.  Where is `c` defined?  ( [mcve] would be good here.)

Comment: The type of `c`  is not shown (before the edit), but it is certain not to be suitable for passing to `strcat` because you have `c = getc(file)` so it should be `int` type.

Comment: Kahalon, step 1: `char c;` --> `int c;`

Comment: `strcat(str, &c);` is invalid as `&c` does not point to a _string_.

Comment: I have added the whole code of this section. I define c as char and not as int because there are signs which I need ('-', ',') etc. how do I do this correctly?

Comment: Remember that `'-'` is type `int` not `char`. You can't test for `EOF` without using `int` which is what the library function `getc` returns, *not* `char`.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have updated c to an int type but the issue still remains

Comment: Read the comment by @chux then. You can't `strcat` a single character, you need a string.

Comment: `char smallstr[2] = {0}; smallstr[0] = c; strcat(str, smallstr);`

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, you solved it :D

Comment: The 2nd `c = getc(file)` loop  certainly returns `EOF`. Perhaps `rewind(file)` before 2nd time through the file.

Answer (score 3):

[`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) expects a NUL-terminated string (array of char) as its second argument, but
`c` is defined as a single character, not an array of char.

To fix this, you can maintain an index into `str`

```
int c;
int j = 0;
for (c = getc(file); c!= EOF; c = getc(file)) {
    if (c != ',' && c != '\n') {
        str[j++] = c;
        str[j] = 0; // keep string NUL-terminated
    } else {
        ret = strtod(str, NULL);
        X[i] = ret;
        i++;
        // reset j
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As `c` is `char` the following is invalid.

```
c = getc(file); c!= EOF;
```

and

```
strcat(str, &c);
```

Both are Undefined behaviours. To sort the first out declare `c` as `int`

The second problem:

```
//You need to create a null char terminated string to use as 
//second parameters of the srtcat. For example, you can define 
//a compound literal - char array containing two elements: c & 
//terminating null character
strcat(str,(char []){c,0});
```

Comment: `c = getc(file); c!= EOF;` is not UB, yet still poor code.  Nifty to use a _compound literal_.

Comment: I did not want to change OPs code too much

Comment: Fair enough to  limit changes to OP code, yet answer's explanation remains amiss.